# QT CreatorL Adding source files from another (parent) directory

Tags: qt, qt4

My Qt project structure is similar to this:

Directory Structure:

```
  |
  |--- dir
  |      |
  |      | - a.c
  |      | - a.h
  |      | - test.pro
  |--- dir1
  |      | - b.c
  |      | - b.h
```

test.pro

```
SOURCES +=  a.c \
            ../dir1/*.c
HEADERS +=  a.h \
            ../dir1/*.h
```

When I try to build the project I get the error:

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target `../dir1/*.c'
```

Is there anyway to include source files which are outside the .pro file?

And also have them show in the Projects pane on the left in Qt Creator?

Comment: I think wild cards are not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcards in qmake (.pro file) work only for files in current project directory. For subfolders it does not work. So the proper solution is to **add each file separately**.

The issue was raised on the Qt bug tracker [QTCREATORBUG-8925](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-8925). The ticked is closed as a new feature request or due to multiple problems:

> Using wildcards in .pro files creates multiple problems, e.g. adding a
>   additional file won't automatically compile it. Nor would deleting a
>   file automatically remove it from the Makefile

However, there is undocumented function listed on the wiki [Undocumented_QMake](http://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake)

> files(glob) — Returns a list of files which match the specified glob
>   pattern.

So, if the above problems of using globbing patterns are acceptable it can be used as

```
SOURCES += $$files(../dir1/*.c)
```